# How to change Stage name in javaFX Web Browser on loading of Web page?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, netbeans-8

> I am creating a web browser using **JavaFx**. Suppose I have a name for my browser **MY BROWSER** . I want that whenever web page(for example http:www.google.com) load then Stage Name should be **MY BROWSER - Google**. How to do it. I have already set my stage name as **MY BROWSER**.

This is constructor of my HomeEngine class.

```
HomeEngine(){
WebView browser = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
webEngine.load("http://google.com");
}
```

I am using making object of this HomeEngine class in my Main Class.

```
HomeEngine browser = new HomeEngine();
```

I had already set Title for my Main class stage as **MY BROWSER**.

```
primaryStage.setTitle("MY BROWSER :"+browser.getWebEngine().getTitle());
```

[Before Loading Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQdL0.png)

[After Loading Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeVA3.png)

Comment: If you know how to set it once, then presumably you know how to set it again...

Comment: @James_D I had set it by stage.setTitle(MY BROWSER). But I want that It should get name automatically from the Current Webpage.

Comment: So call `stage.setTitle(...)` and pass in the title from the web page. No-one can really help you unless they know what the actual problem is. Please read [the help pages on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: I'm not trying to be smart. Your question is not answerable as it stands - I literally do not know what you are asking, which is why I directed you to resources on how to improve the question.

Comment: @James_D I have tried this  stage.setTitle("MYBROWSER-"+webview.getWebEngine().getTitle()); But first it is returning "MYBROWSER-null" . Then after loading webpage (e.g.http://www.google.com) it is returning "Google".    But I want "MYBROWSER-Google".

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to explain fully what you have tried, and what the results were. Ideally include a [MCVE] (you should be able to create something with this functionality in just a few dozen lines of code). It seems hard to believe that `stage.setTitle("MYBROWSER-"+webview.getWebEngine().getTitle(‌​));` could possibly result in a title of just `"Google"`. In general the code you suggest should basically work.

Comment: @James_D Now I edited my question with full explanation.

Comment: I can't answer this from the snippets of information you have posted. Maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer `according to what i understood from the comments and the question` is very simple

but at first let's understand the problem you sometimes have a `null` title of the loaded web page and this is due to two things

1. you try to get the title before the page being loaded completely,so you must put a listener when a page is completely loaded, get its title as the following simple sample of code

   ```
   browser.getEngine().getLoadWorker().
               stateProperty().
               addListener(new ChangeListener()
               {
                   @Override
                   public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue)
                   {
                       if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)
                       {
                           primaryStage.setTitle("My Browser : " + browser.getEngine().getTitle());
                       }
                   }
               });
   ```

   and as you knew the `WebView` works asynchronously
2. the page itself has no title so when the `WebView` tries to get the title it finds nothing `ie:null`

hope this is useful

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it is **not working**. Still It is returning only **Google** instead of **My Browser: Google**.

Comment: I think you didn't use primaryStage.setTitle("My Browser : " + browser.getEngine().getTitle()); in the ChangeListener method, so can you share the complete code with us? @DungeonMaster